# GoogleMobileAds.framework: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

Tags: admob, xcode7, code-signing

I'm trying to test admob integration in an iOS app. I manually added the framework:

1. Embedded Binaries
2. Linked Frameworks and Libraries
3. Embed Frameworks

I also disabled bit code, as Google's framework was built without. So far so good.

The following error is presented:

> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign [...]/internal/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/Swift/admob/BannerExample/build/Release-iphoneos/BannerExample.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework:

**> bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable Command**

> /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue earlier, just remove it from the embedded libraries!

Comment: Thanks christopher, Saved lots of time.